# Replace(Invert) Code based on mid letter

Tags: c++, replace

Currently i have to convert a thousands of codes to another format of code.

`Options.Autoskip = fileLogger->write("AutoSkip");`

this to

`fileLogger->write("AutoSkip") = Options.Autoskip;`

Basically i have to  Inverting code based on middle "=" letter, but i dont know what should i use/ what should i do to achieve this result. I tried Notepad++ but seems like it doesnt support this sort of "complex" replacing works.

If anyone have any idea/programs to achieve this result, Please let me know.

Comment: what are the parts that are same for each occurence you need to replace? (i mean the example you show here could be done with a simple search & replace and I guess you dont want to refactor every occurence of `a = b;` ;)

Comment: Either use regular expressions or write a small program or script to do it.

Comment: This seems like the perfect job for a custom [clang tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) check with a fix-it implementation. Shouldn't be hard to write the code to identify the problematic pattern and the code to implement the fixup. Then simply run clang tidy over the entire code base. Compiler based tools are awesome for stuff like this ;-)

Comment: You could write a simple tool to do this for you. Using C# this should be fairly trivial

Comment: @user463035818 Any Tool you can suggest?

Comment: @JesperJuhl wow, that would be so much overengineering, I must see it! Any chance you can link a sample?

Comment: @sehe why would it be overengineering? Clang tidy checks (and fixups) can often be written in 40-60 lines of code..

Comment: I guess that's a no, then.

Comment: @Bigiansen I really dont sure about regular expressions can fix this issue :/

Comment: The way to fix this issue is basically inverting a = b; to b = a; but i cant find this sort of fitting tools for me. Clang tidy doesnt support windows i guess?

Comment: "Any Tool you can suggest?" as I said, for the example you show here any texteditor with a search/replace feature is fine, or replacing any occurence of `a = b;` with `b = a;` should be easy with regexpressions, but I guess you are looking for a more complicated pattern, hence my question: what is the pattern?

Comment: @user463035818 ah, the pattern is this. 
Options.(Unknown Words) = Filelogger->write(Unknown Words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure there is only ever one `=` per line, then regex capture groups can do this just fine for you.

For example, you can do this with `Replace...` (Ctrl+H) in Notepad++ (and probably several other editors that support regex):

Find what: `^(.*?) = (.*?);$`
Replace with: `\2 = \1;`

`^` Matches the line start.
`(.*?)` non-greedily matches anything and puts it into a capture group (you could probably get away with greedy matching here though).
`$` matches the line end.

`\1` is the first capture group (left hand side) and `\2` is the second capture group (right hand side). Switch them in the replace and tada!

Comment: You are my lifesaver. Thank you really much. i'll start to learn regex expression :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Vim:

```
something else;
something else;
Options.Autoskip = fileLogger->write("AutoSkip");
Options.Hollowlens = fileLogger->write("HollowLens");
something else;
Options.Fluxcapactor = fileLogger->write("FluxCapactor");
something else;
Options.Answer = fileLogger->write("Answer");
```

Enter Ex command:

```
:%s/\v(Options\.\w+)(\s*\=\s*)(fileLogger-\>write\(".{-}"\));/\3\2\1;/g
```

Result:

```
something else;
something else;
fileLogger->write("AutoSkip") = Options.Autoskip;
fileLogger->write("HollowLens") = Options.Hollowlens;
something else;
fileLogger->write("FluxCapactor") = Options.Fluxcapactor;
something else;
fileLogger->write("Answer") = Options.Answer;
```

---

Using sed:

```
sed -i 's/\(Options\.\w\+\)\(\s*=\s*\)\(fileLogger->write(".*\?")\);/\3\2\1;/' src/*.cpp
```

Comment: Also Thanks. i didnt use linux based coding software tho.

Comment: You didn't? My bad.